# How many clients can connect to this server?

Tags: c#

How many clients can connect to this server?

```
private void btnserverconect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1_Load(sender, e);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        server =
            new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                   ProtocolType.Tcp);

        //IPAddress local = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        EndPoint destination = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
        server.Bind(destination);
        server.Listen(5);
        Thread wait = new Thread(wa);
        wait.Start();
    }
    catch(Exception) {
        MessageBox.Show("connection error !");
    }
}

void wa()
{
    label1.Text = "please wait...";
    server = server.Accept();
    label1.Text = "connect";
    while (true) {
        try {
            byte[]by = new byte[100];
            int n = server.Receive(by);
            lstserver.Items.Add("client :" +
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(by, 0, n));
        }
        catch(Exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many clients have you *tried* to connect to that server?

Comment: Pass the value you get from `server.Accept()` to a new thread and continue to `Accept`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Accept()` is only going to be called once.

So one client.

Comment: Please help me do what I do? Write the code.

Comment: What do you want to do? I haven't seen that yet. I thought you just wanted to know how many clients could connect...

Comment: I want to be connected to the second clients to the server

Comment: That might be difficult to do cleanly, since your server is currently a stack-allocated variable in a _button click handler_. Much nicer would be keeping the GUI dedicated to GUI tasks and putting all the TCP-based server stuff in different objects.

Answer (score 1):

After this line:

```
server = server.Accept();
```

The listening socket isn't referenced anymore, as the `server` variable now points to the socket that talks to the connected (one) client. Also you ignore disconnect messages from that client (when `Socket.Receive()` returns 0).

Ps. You're trying to update what I guess is a listbox (`lstserver`) from another thread than the GUI thread, possibly causing an exception that is silently ignored, and not updating the listbox.